# Command line showing "Wireless" as a heading

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

Opened up terminal, and I can see the last time I logged in, a bash error saying a certain file does not exist, and then "Wireless" followed by some numbers in front of every command I enter.

Upon entering exit, I get stuck in a [Process Completed] message, and cannot do anything else.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3eGB.jpg - Link to what my terminal screen looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wireless-*` is your host-name. Most likely it was assigned automatically by the wifi-router you were connected to last time you started your computer.

`[Process completed]` is the default behaviour for the macOS Terminal.app. It does not close the window when the shell exists, but shows this message. You can change this by opening Terminal's Preferences, then selecting the Profile you're using, and then switching to the "Shell" tab: There is the option "When the shell exists:" where you can select "Close the Window".

[image: Terminal Preferences]

Comment: Thank you very much. I was just confused by the addition of the wireless-*, when previously I had never seen it before.